# finding nth row from database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

**i is the parameter that is caught from different page.I got the value of i as 1 it should show the nth row of table.but it is not displaying anything.**

```
int i=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("index"));
i=i-1;
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","SYSTEM","SYSTEM");
String query="select * from employee1  limit 1 offset i";
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

     String name = rs.getString(2); 
     int salary = rs.getInt(3); 
PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
res.setContentType("text/html");
out.println("<form action='update' method=''>");
    out.println("Name:<input type='text' name='name' value="+name+"/>");
    out.println("Salary:<input type='text' name='salary' value="+salary+ "/>");
    out.println("<input type='submit' name='update' />");
out.println("</form>");
```

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong: `"select * from employee1  limit 1 offset i";`

Your i variable isn't substituted.

It should be `"select * from employee1  limit 1 offset ?"`. And substitute this using `pst.setInteger(i)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String query="select * from employee1  limit 1 offset " + i;
```

So, when your i=10, assume, your code would be

```
String query="select * from employee1  limit 1 offset " + 10;
```

and query would be

```
select * from employee1  limit 1 offset 10
```

Whereas, your original query would be,

```
select * from employee1  limit 1 offset i
```

Because the "i" within quotes inside a string would not be evaluated/replaced. And your query would not even compile!!